# Magento Helper Directory Structure

Tags: magento

I have a custom module and everything works fine.  I'm adding and admin panel portion to the module and would like a separate admin helper.  I know I can create and call my admin helper like this:

```
app/code/local/namespace/module/helper/Admin.php

class Namespace_Module_Helper_Admin extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract....

$helper = Mage::helper('namespace_module/admin');
```

And everything works great.

I was really wanting the structure for my admin helper to be something like this:

```
app/code/local/namespace/module/helper/admin/Data.php
```

But can't figure out the how to set that up in config.xml and then call the helper.

My initial thought was to setup the config like this:

```
...
<helper>
   <namespace_module>
      <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
   </namespace_module>
   <namespace_module_admin>
      <class>Namespace_Module_Admin_Helper</class>
   </namespace_module_admin>
</helper>
...
```

Then call the helper like this:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('namespace_module_admin');
```

But this doesn't work.

Is it possible to have a second helper for my module in a helper directory child directory? If so could someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this but I think you have some typos. I was able to register a new helper using your approach with settings like this:

```
<helpers>
    <namespace_module>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Helper</class>
    </namespace_module>
    <namespace_module_admin>
        <class>Namespace_Module_Helper_Admin</class>
    </namespace_module_admin>
</helpers>
```

The helper file itself was at the path: `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Helper/Admin/Data.php`

The helper class looks like this:

```
class Namespace_Module_Helper_Admin_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function test()
    {
        return 'test';
    }
}
```

And I was able to invoke it with the syntax:

```
Mage::helper('namespace_module_admin')->test();
```

So it is possible that your issue is due to your file/class name not matching up with the location Magento’s autoloader was expecting. For example your `<class>Namespace_Module_Admin_Helper</class>` should map to the (improper) directory `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Admin/Helper` rather than the expected `app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Helper/Admin`.

Comment: No typos but your code did provide the solution.  I was putting the `Admin` before the `Helper` in the class name, as soon as I moved it to after in both the config.xml and the Helper/Admin/Data.php, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks fine and absolutely right. You have only one mistake in config.xml. You should name node `<helpers>` instead of `<helper>`

Comment: Unfortunately that is just a typo on my part, in my module I am using `<helpers>`.  With everything setup as shown I get this error: Fatal error: Class 'Namespace_Module_Admin_Helper_Data' not found in /files/app/Mage.php on line 546

Comment: Are you sure that you named all files correctly? I mean the camelcase in filenames and valid paths.